# AHK issue with mousewheel key remap

Tags: autohotkey

I am having trouble with my script, and I don't understand why its not working the way I want it to.

What I want: when I use my mouse wheel up, I want it to use my health flask, or send the keyboard '1 key' once, and when I use mouse wheel down, I want it to use my quicksilver flask (send the keyboard 'key 5' once), but what is happening, is it's repeating, so instead of using the flask once, it uses the whole flask, or rather it hits the keyboard key 1 or 5 several times, its auto repeating.

The question I have is: how can I stop it from repeating with the send command, since in the application, if I hold 1 or 5 it does not auto repeat, I have to click it again. So the send command is autorepeating, and I don't want it to.

I thought maybe it was because when I did the mousewheel down or up it was doing it multiple times, but when I set it to 1 in windows in mouse control panel, it did not help.

Here is my script, I thought it was simple...

```
#IfWinActive Path of Exile

WheelUp::Send {1}

WheelDown::Send {5}
```

Before I tried to use the send command, I tried to do it with this script:

```
#IfWinActive Path of Exile

WheelUp::1

WheelDown::5
```

And this script doesn't work at all, with the application... but it works outside of the the application if I don't use the `#IfWinActive` line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: afaik, you don't need the `{` `}`. // Are you sure that your mouse is not triggering the Hotkey multiple times? You could check it by incrementing a global counter after each hotkey trigger, and retrieve its value with a third hotkey or via the script main window (task bar double click). If you are sure, you could try out `sendEvent` or `sendRaw` instead of plain `Send` which defaults to `sendPlay`, if not stated otherwise. I wouldn't know any other solution

Comment: I think it is my mouse being overly sensitive, because if I try really hard not to slide the wheel too much, it only uses it once.

Comment: @Blauhirn Nevermind, I figured it out on my own, Not sure if this is the best method, but here is what worked:    #IfWinActive Path of Exile

WheelUp::
Send, {1 down}
Sleep 5000
Send, {1 up}
return

WheelDown::
Send, {5 down}
Sleep 5000
Send, {5 up}
return

Comment: glad it worked. you should post it as the answer and accept your answer then. I'll also post another idea in case someone else has a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is your mouse which triggers the hotkey multiple times, you may try the following (not tested):

```
hotkey, ifWinActive, Path of Exile
hotkey, WheelUp, send1, on
hotkey, WheelDown, send5, on
hotkey, ifWinActive
return

send1:
send 1
hotkey, WheelUp, send1, off ; prevents WheelUp to send 1 more than one time for 1000 ms
sleep, 1000
hotkey, ifWinActive, Path of Exile
hotkey, WheelUp, send1, on
hotkey, ifWinActive
return

send5:
send 5
hotkey, WheelDown, send5, off ; prevents WheelDown to send 5 more than one time for 1000 ms
sleep, 1000
hotkey, ifWinActive, Path of Exile
hotkey, WheelDown, send5, on
hotkey, ifWinActive
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first script (below) sends exactly one key-down event followed immediately by one key-up event, for each notch of the mouse wheel. The keystroke is not repeated unless the mouse wheel is still moving (as reported by your mouse). The Send command does **not** autorepeat.

```
#IfWinActive Path of Exile
WheelUp::Send {1}
WheelDown::Send {5}
```

It's fairly common for games to not respond as reliably to Send as other applications, hence the FAQ [Why do Hotstrings, Send, and Click have no effect in certain games?](http://ahkscript.org/docs/FAQ.htm#games), which provides some possible solutions. For instance, I would suggest using [SetKeyDelay](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm)'s *PressDuration* parameter to increase the delay between "pressing" and "releasing" the key. Alternatively, you can use `Send {1 down}`, `Sleep xxx` and `Send {1 up}`.

You may want to add `{Blind}` to the front of each send, like `Send {Blind}1`, otherwise it may interfere with your use of modifier keys. For instance, if you are holding Ctrl, `Send 1` will automatically "release" Ctrl, send 1, then "press" Ctrl back down.

If your mouse is causing the hotkey to trigger multiple times, Blauhirn's answer may work, but it can be simplified (with additions as described above):

```
SetKeyDelay 20, 20

#IfWinActive Path of Exile

WheelUp::
    Send {Blind}{1}
    Sleep 500  ; Wait 500ms
    return  ; WheelUp can't fire a second instance until the first returns.

WheelDown::
    Send {Blind}{5}
    Sleep 500
    return
```

The drawback of this simple method is that if you activate one hotkey and then the other hotkey before the first Sleep returns (i.e. within 500ms in this example), both will be blocked until the second Sleep finishes.  Reducing the sleep time would help avoid this.

**Your second script is invalid.** That is, `WheelUp::1` is invalid, as [documented](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm):

> The following keys are not supported by the built-in remapping method:
>
> - The mouse wheel (WheelUp/Down/Left/Right).

The reason is that unlike other keys, the WheelUp/Down "pseudo-keys" can only be *pressed*, not *released*. So when you remap `WheelUp::1`, it maps WheelUp to `{1 down}` and never sends `{1 up}`; that is, it presses 1 but never releases it.